# How can I specify the current ResultObject in Geomagics with a python script

Tags: python

I am trying to automate the report creation in Geomagics, using the `create_report()` function.

However, we have several sets of results, which need to be reviewed by a human operator (within the Geomagics interface) before the various reports can be created if the results are considered acceptable. Since `create_report()` works on the current `ResultObject`, I'd like to be able to set this to all my results in a loop.

(Alternatively, there might be a way to write a report for a specific object, not just the current result?)

Comment: First of all, I am not a python specialist, but I am working much in the conceptual design area of geomagics. Just for clarifying purposes, you want the sets of result to be in a loop, so that the operator says->create, then sees the next set of results says -> create etc. etc. to your alternative question: yeah, i think this should be pretty easy to do, my first try would be to iterate over the result sets fetching the objects data, storing them and saving them into there very own report

Comment: But is there a way to specify the object data used for the report? From what I've seen, create_report() cannot work on any object, just the current ResultObject (which I've found no way to set programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Can you break the problem down further ?

How should the operator see the results, as a spreadsheet or some other way ?

For example, can you script outside of GeoMagic to fetch result sets and display those to the operator, then write back approved results to another dataset

then at the end, create the report within GeoMagic from the "approved" dataset.

Comment: No, the request I have is that the user must be able to view the scene within Geomagics, perform some additional manipulations if needed, and generate the pdf reports as a form of confirmation/signature.

Comment: ah ok.  I'm not familiar with GeoMagic, just wondered if an outside view might help break the problem down. Sorry I can't help further - looks like a reasonable user requirement here, so surprised there isn't some way to do this